# Remove row lines in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for some web app I'm forced to do (I'm not a web developer) and I can't find a way to disable the row lines for tables.

As you can see from the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables), the default table style contains line rows.

Regards,

Comment: Tried that can't find anything that would be obvious, none of the elements involve use any css class.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Add this to your main CSS:

```
table td {
    border-top: none !important;
}
```

Use this for newer versions of bootstrap:

```
.table th, .table td { 
     border-top: none !important; 
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I put it in the html/head/style part, but chrome displays it with strike-through as though it isn't used. Any ideas?

Comment: @MartinWickman this answer was written for an earlier version of the bootstrap (one point something at the time) so this method requires the `!important` rule to work, but you can evade that by making the selector a bit more specific like so: 
`.table th, .table td {
    border-top: none;
}`

Comment: Don't globally override styles like this.  Use a new CSS class, rather than overriding the default for ALL tables.  ```.table-borderless td,
.table-borderless th {
    border: 0;
}``` from http://coderwall.com/p/hfurca

Comment: @PeterDavis The css line came straight from the bootstrap's stylesheet, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v1.4.0/bootstrap.css line 1121 .. zero research before downvoting.

Comment: @AndresIlich - Right -- bootstrap sets a default style for all tables.  I downvoted because it is a bad idea to override at the global level.  You will cause unintended consequences to tables that SHOULD have borders.

Comment: @PeterDavis you did not understand, i agree that global styles should not be used but per the question it was the "only" way to fix the issue..this "issue" was fixed on later versions of the bootstrap, which used classes instead of directly adding styles to the `table` rule. Once more, the line came straight from the bootstrap's stylesheet, semantics aside it was the only way to fix the issue in that environment.

Comment: @AndresIlich I think what PeterDavis was trying to say was instead of overwriting global styles he rather should add a no-borders class to the tables that he's targeting and style that accordingly. I think dex412's answer expresses exactly what he meant. Don't get why you insist that overriding globals was the only solution here.

Answer (score 51):

In Bootstrap 3 I've added a table-no-border class

```
.table-no-border>thead>tr>th, 
.table-no-border>tbody>tr>th, 
.table-no-border>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table-no-border>thead>tr>td, 
.table-no-border>tbody>tr>td, 
.table-no-border>tfoot>tr>td {
  border-top: none; 
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me while the others didn't (including the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075794/bootstrap-table-without-stripe-borders)). Using Bootstrap 3 via `bootstrap-sass` in Rails.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work. I'm using a responsive table, and modified its class (`.table-responsive`) to none border.

Answer (score 15):

bootstrap.min.css is more specific than your own stylesheet if you just use .table td. So use this instead:

```
.table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>td {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: I had to do something similar to target just a few cells: ``.table > tbody > tr > td.no-line {
    border-top: none;
}``

Comment: Together with a class intersection selector, this nailed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me..

```
.table-no-border>thead>tr>th, 
.table-no-border>tbody>tr>th, 
.table-no-border>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table-no-border>thead>tr>td, 
.table-no-border>tbody>tr>td, 
.table-no-border>tfoot>tr>td,
.table-no-border>tbody,
.table-no-border>thead,
.table-no-border>tfoot{
  border-top: none !important; 
  border-bottom: none !important; 
}
```

Had to whip out the !important to make it stick.

Comment: it's working but not like that it's work for using  `!important`

Answer (score 0):

The other way around, if you have problems ADDING the lines to your panel dont forget to add the  to your TABLE.
By default (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels), it is suppose to add the line but It helped me to add the  tag so now the row lines are shown.

The following example "probably" wont display the lines between rows:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table">
        <tr><td> Hi 1! </td></tr>
        <tr><td> Hi 2! </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The following example WILL display the lines between rows:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table">
        <thead></thead>
        <tr><td> Hi 1! </td></tr>
        <tr><td> Hi 2! </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same question from a friend. My suggestion which does not require `!Important` looks like this: I add a custom class "`no-border`" which can be added to the bootstrap table.

```
.table.no-border tr td, .table.no-border tr th {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

You can see my go at a [solution here](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/ogVQqG/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix if you have only a table or two where you want to remove the lines: Apply "style="border-top: none;" to each and every
<th> and/or <td> tag within a table.
Table header:

```
<th style="border-top: none;">
```

Table data:

```
<td style="border-top: none;">
```