# Twitter-bootstrap table how to get only the outer border lines and not in between rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
```

I used to have `table-bordered` in there but it is giving me the lines in between rows. I just want the top, bottom, left and right lines on the outside of the entire table and no lines in between rows.

Also, I tried to do baby steps first and therefore tried to remove the lines in between rows as suggested here
[Remove row lines in twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875367/remove-row-lines-bootstrap)
and the solution given

```
table td {
    border-top: none;
}
```

didn't work for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe your CSS isn't getting picked up because it isn't specific enough. the css that defines the border in the twitter bootstrap code is:

```
.table th, .table td { /*css*/ }
```

but your code is

```
table td { /* css */}
```

the first is considered more specific because it uses the class ".table" instead of the table element as the selector and thus has higher priority.

Made a small jsfiddle to do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/EfUAa/11/

```
.table td, .table th {
    border: none;
}

table.table.table-condensed {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here's a good resource on css specificity:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Also make sure that your css file is loaded after the bootstrap file.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else seeing this recently, you can simply add `border` class to your table, and that should give it the **OUTER** border.

### Table with outer border

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table border">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Table with no border

`table-borderless` would produce a table **without any borders, outer or inner**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table table-borderless">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Table with outer border, and no innder borders

To produce a table with the outer border only, and no innder borders, simply add both `table-borderless` and `border` classes to the table as such:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="table border table-borderless">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

---

Hope this helps anyone out there without having to use CSS etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to your CSS style:

```
<style>
.table{
outline-style: solid;
outline-width: 2px;
</style>
```

Hope it helps. More on "outline-style":https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline-style.asp .

Answer (score 1):

Add Bootstrap class "border" to table tag and add class "border-0" to th,td tags

Comment: No need to add zero border if you add the border to the table class, at least with v5.