# Bootstrap table without stripe / borders

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm kinda stuck with a CSS problem while using Bootstrap. I'm also using Angular JS with Angular UI.bootstrap (which might be part of the problem).

I'm making a website that displays data in a table.
Sometime, the data contains object that I have to display in tables.
So I want to put borderless tables inside a normal table while keeping inside separation lines for the borderless tables.

But it seems that even if I specifically say to not show the borders on a table, it is forced:

HTML:

```
<table class='table borderless'>
```

CSS:

```
.borderless table {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

So here, what I want is just the inside borders.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 2.3.1

Comment: with bootstrap 4: .borderless tr td, .borderless tr th {border: none;}

Answer (score 348, accepted):

The border styling is set on the `td` elements.

html:

```
<table class='table borderless'>
```

css:

```
.borderless td, .borderless th {
    border: none;
}
```

**Update:** Since Bootstrap 4.1 you can use `.table-borderless` to remove the border.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#borderless-table

Comment: Note: you should also add `.borderless th`, as the Bootstrap styling applies to `<th>` as well.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24830641/1992780).

Comment: I had to add border: none !important; to make it work.

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva ..or you just add the css style in the line with `style=`, or put it in a customized file and __ensure that it is loaded later than Bootstrap css file__, to override the Bootstrap default style. CSS are loaded with order; the latter overwrites the former, the more specific overwrites the more general ones.

Comment: with bootstrap 4: `.borderless tr td, .borderless tr th {border: none;} `

Comment: !important is very important

Comment: For boostrap > 4.1 use `<table class='table table-borderless'>` per Max below

Answer (score 367):

Using Bootstrap 3.2.0 I had problem with Brett Henderson solution (borders were always there), so I improved it:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
```

**CSS**

```
.table-borderless > tbody > tr > td,
.table-borderless > tbody > tr > th,
.table-borderless > tfoot > tr > td,
.table-borderless > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-borderless > thead > tr > td,
.table-borderless > thead > tr > th {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `th`-element in the body: `.borderless tbody tr th` (as used in the [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-example))

Comment: @DavidePastore If this is only for the tables, maybe prefix it with `.table-`, as Bootstrap 3 does for other table related classes (for example `table-striped`, etc.). So name will be `table-borderless`.

Comment: Works for v4.0.0-alpha.2.  Thanks!

Comment: I was still getting a border along the bottom of the table until I added `.table-borderless,` to the beginning of this style specification.

Comment: I don't see `table-borderless` in this doc https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables . From where it came?

Answer (score 26):

similar to the rest, but more specific:

```
    table.borderless td,table.borderless th{
     border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need important with .table.borderless

Comment: @Sam Jones - Does this affect the entire table ? I want some rows to have bottom border. I want border-top gone.

Comment: !important is very important

Answer (score 20):

Don’t add the `.table` class to your `<table>` tag. From the Bootstrap docs on [tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables):

> For basic styling—light padding and **only horizontal dividers**—add the base class `.table` to any `<table>`. It may seem super redundant, but given the widespread use of tables for other plugins like calendars and date pickers, we've opted to isolate our custom table styles.

Comment: Even like this :
html :
<table class='borderless'>
css :
.borderless {
 border:none;
}

It doesn't work.

Comment: I’d suggest using the Web Inspector in Chrome then and seeing where any borders are being applied, as tables by default don’t have borders when using Bootstrap for interoperability with other components like date-pickers etc.

Comment: This worked great, I am just using the 'table-condensed' and other variants without the 'table' class and got rid of the borders. Great tip as the docs threw me a bit there.

Answer (score 16):

Since Bootstrap v4.1 you can add `table-borderless` to your table, see [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#borderless-table):

```
<table class='table table-borderless'>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using that and still getting borders which makes no sense to me, that's how I got here and saw the suggestions for 4.x and up but it still shows borders, so I need to know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Install bootstrap either with npm or cdn link

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">First</th>
  <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td>@fat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
    <td>@twitter</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

get the reference with this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#borderless-table)

Answer (score 6):

In my CSS:

```
.borderless tr td {
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

In my directive:

```
<table class='table borderless'>
    <tr class='borderless' ....>
```

I didn't put the 'borderless' for the td element.

Tested and it worked!
All the borders and paddings are completely stripped off.

Answer (score 5):

I expanded the Bootstrap table styles as Davide Pastore did, but with that method the styles are applied to all child tables as well, and they don't apply to the footer.

A better solution would be imitating the core Bootstrap table styles, but with your new class:

```
.table-borderless>thead>tr>th
.table-borderless>thead>tr>td
.table-borderless>tbody>tr>th
.table-borderless>tbody>tr>td
.table-borderless>tfoot>tr>th
.table-borderless>tfoot>tr>td {
    border: none;
}
```

Then when you use `<table class='table table-borderless'>` only the specific table with the class will be bordered, not any table in the tree.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<table class='borderless'>
```

### CSS

```
.borderless {
 border:none;
}
```

Note: What you were doing before was not working because your css code was targeting a table within your .borderless table (which probably didn't exist)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread and that you've picked an answer, but I thought I'd post this as it is relevant for anyone else that is currently looking.

There is no reason to create new CSS rules, simply undo the current rules and the borders will disappear.

```
    .table>tbody>tr>th,
    .table>tbody>tr>td {
        border-top: 0;
    }
```

going forward, anything styled with

```
    .table
```

will show no borders.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `border-` class from Boostrap 4

```
<td class="border-0"></td>
```

or

```
<table class='table border-0'></table>
```

Be sure to end the class input with the last change you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use `hidden` instead of `none`:

```
.hide-bottom {
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me.

```
<td style="border-top: none;">;
```

The key is you need to add border-top to the `<td>`

Comment: Inline CSS attributes are considered [bad practice](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#CSSattributes).

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the game here but FWIW: adding `.table-bordered` to a `.table` just wraps the table with a border, albeit by adding a full border to every cell.

But removing `.table-bordered` still leaves the rule lines.  It's a semantic issue, but in keeping with BS3+ nomenclature I've used this set of overrides:

```css
.table.table-unruled>tbody>tr>td,
.table.table-unruled>tbody>tr>th {
  border-top: 0 none transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 none transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      .table
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        .table .table-bordered
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <table class="table table-unruled">
        .table .table-unruled
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-unruled">
        .table .table-bordered .table-unruled
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most examples seem to be too specific and/or bloated.

Here was my trimmed down solution using Bootstrap 4.0.0 (4.1 includes `.table-borderless` but still alpha)...

```
.table-borderless th{border:0;}
.table-borderless td{border:0;}
```

Similar to many proposed solutions, but minimal bytes

Note: Ended up here because I was viewing BS4.1 references and couldn't figure out why `.table-borderless` was not working with my 4.0 sources (eg: operator error, duh)

Comment: Correction: 4.1 is not alpha. Assumed it was since I was not using that version 

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, one must also use border-spacing in the table class, like:

> border-spacing: 0 !important;

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap supports scss, and he has a special variables. If this is a case then you can add in your main variables.scss file

```
$table-border-width: 0;
```

More info here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6ffb0b48e455430f8a5359ed689ad64c1143fac2/scss/_variables.scss#L347-L380

Answer (score 0):

Mi solucion fue esta:

```html
<table width="100%" border='0'>
 <tr align='center'>
   <td>Data1</td>
   <td>Data2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```